# Calculation of the pressure force on the wing profile via SALOME and python

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the pressure force F=pressure*length (because in 2D) on a wing profile.
I used the example of the MEDCOUPLING agitator, but I can't adapt it correctly.
It seems to me that I have to :
-retrieve the mesh from the corresponding .med
-retrieve the corresponding pressure field
-make it an array

The problem is that :
-I can't get the edge of the airfoil to measure it
-I can't determine and select the pressures applying to this edge
-I can't determine and select the pressures that apply to this edge. In your opinion, should I first extract the cells corresponding to the edge and then extract the corresponding pressure, or do you see other possibilities?

Thanks

```
import system 
import salome
import medcoupling as mc
import numpy as np
salome.salome_init()
import salome_notebook
notebook = salome_notebook.NoteBook()
sys.path.insert(0, r'/home/b72882/Documents')
import GEOM
from salome.geom import geomBuilder
import math
import SALOMEDS
import  SMESH, SALOMEDS
from salome.smesh import smeshBuilder

ailMesh2DMc=mc.ReadUMeshFromFile("naca10.med", "MeshFlow10", 0)
m2DSurf,desc,descI,revDesc,revDescI = ailMesh2DMc.buildDescendingConnectivity() 
nbOf2DCellSharing = revDescI.deltaShiftIndex() 
ids2 = nbOf2DCellSharing.findIdsEqual(1)
ailSkinMc = m2DSurf[ids2]  
f = mc.MEDCouplingFieldDouble.New(mc.ON_CELLS, mc.ONE_TIME)
f.setTime(1,200,201)   
f.setArray(ailMesh2DMc.computeCellCenterOfMass())
f.setMesh(ailMesh2DMc)
f.setName("Pressure")
mc.WriteField("naca10.med",f,True)
f2 = mc.ReadFieldCell("naca10.med", f.getMesh().getName(), 0, f.getName(), 200, 201)
arr = f2.getArray()
arr=mc.DataArrayDouble(ailMesh2DMc.getNumberOfCells(),1)
ids = arr.findIdsInRange(-6.,6.)  
pressOnAilMc = f2[ids] 
offsetsOfTupleIdsInField = revDescI[ids]   
tupleIdsInField = revDesc[offsetsOfTupleIdsInField] 
pressOnSkinAilMc = pressOnAilMc[tupleIdsInField]  
pressOnSkinAilMc.setMesh(ailSkinMc)   
pressSkin = pressOnAilMc.getArray()  
pressSkin *= 1e5  
areaSkin = ailSkinMc.getMeasureField(True).getArray() 
forceSkin = pressSkin*areaSkin
normalSkin = ailSkinMc.buildOrthogonalField().getArray()
forceVectSkin = forceSkin*normalSkin
# mesh1d,lskin,di,r,ri = ailMesh2DMc.explodeIntoEdges()
force = forceVectSkin/lSkin
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This doesn't feel like a coding problem, but a conceptual problem about your task. If it is a coding problem can you clarify specifically what you want your code to do, and what you have tried, ideally using an easy to understand minimal example that we can run at home?

Comment: Thank you! As I wrote above, I am trying to calculate the pressure force (as a float). 
The code portion I posted is the minimum I think I can write to start solving the problem. Also, I don't have any additional examples. 
By the way, another problem that occurs to me (in the lasts lines) is that the area array and the pressure array are not the same size, so how can I extract the value of pressure and 'area' / length needed (when the shape and size functions are not effective) ?